# Complexity of linear programming

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, linear-programming, approximation-hardness, polynomial-time

It is known that Linear Programming (LP) is P-complete. 
I am interested in approximation algorithms for LP.

There are numerous inapproximability results for NP optimization problems,
e.g. it is NP-hard to achieve approximation ratio better than 7/8 for MAX-3SAT.

> Are there similar P-hardness results for approximation optimization problems in P?
>   In particular, is it known if LP is P-hard to approximate?

Comment: An LP is an optimization also: $\max c^\top x$ such that $Ax \le b$

Comment: Yeah, but the usual notions of approximation don't apply. What if the optimal objective value is zero? What if it's negative?

Comment: Negativity doesn't change anything if you replace the usual A/OPT by |A - OPT|/|OPT|. As for when OPT is $0$, that problem occurs even outside LPs: one response is "this shows that approximating LPs is also P-complete" and the other would be to relax to a $(\alpha, \beta)$ style approximation.

Comment: OP, as Suresh points out, the answer to your question will depend on what kind of approximation you ask about  Can you clarify what you have in mind?

Comment: The feasibility problem with no objective is already P-complete. Adding in the promise that a feasible solution exists does nothing to help identify a solution, as otherwise the prover can guess that a solution exists and work from there. It's hard to imagine a particularly useful objective function / approximation guarantee pair we can tack on to an already P-complete problem that suddenly makes the problem not P-hard.

Answer (score 6):

See the paper "[A parallel approximation algorithm for positive linear programming.](https://doi.org/10.1145/167088.167211)" by Luby and Nisan. (Some kinds of) linear programs can be approximated in log^(O(1)) n time.

Comment: For positive linear programs a more up to date paper is that of Mahoney et al which also has references to several other papers. https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6333/